# XSLT error: Cannot find a template named X

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a problem with call-template, I'm getting error:

> Cannot find a template named getIndex

Syntax seems to be correct. I tried with `apply-template` and all was fine. I don't have any idea why this error appeared.

Here is example XSLT file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Created with Liquid Studio 2019 (https://www.liquid-technologies.com) -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Document">
        <xsl:element name="Document">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Produkt">
        <xsl:element name="Produkt">
            <xsl:element name="Index">
                <xsl:call-template name="getIndex"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="getIndex">
        <xsl:value-of select="Index"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question: you can simplify your code by using *literal result elements* - e.g.  `<Document>` instead of `<xsl:element name="Document">`. Use `xsl:element` when the name needs to calculated dynamically at runtime.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change

```
<xsl:template match="getIndex">
```

to

```
<xsl:template name="getIndex">
              ^^^^
```

In general:

- Use `<xsl:template match="`*pattern*`">` for `xsl:apply-templates`.
- Use `<xsl:template name="`*name*`">` for `xsl:call-template`.